# Git 'merge', but specify remote/local/base with commits in same branch

Tags: git, merge

My conundrum is this. A member of my team modified a vendor component. This component was then upgraded to a current version, overwriting my team's changes.

The portion in question had significant changes made by my teammate, but minimal changes added by the upgrade. What I have is this:

```
---component version 1.0----team change A---team change B---component version 2.0
        (stock)                                              (result of upgrade)
```

What I want is to do the merge like so:

```
          ----team change A---team change B
         /                                 \
---component version 1.0                    successful 'merge'
        (stock)                            /
         \------------component version 2.0
                       (result of upgrade)
```

The rationale is that applying the team changes is easier if we can see the vendor changes from `component version 1.0` to `component version 2.0`, our changes from `component version 1.0` to `team change B`and merge these two sets of changes.

As I understand it, the only way to do this would be to reset the branch to `team change B`,  checkout a new branch from `component version 1.0` and apply the diff between `component version 1.0` and `component version 2.0` as a patch, merge the branches created, and commit the resolution.

What I'm hoping is there's a way to basically simulate a merge like `git merge --BASE='component version 1.0' --LOCAL='team change B' --REMOTE='component version 2.0'` such that I could use a merge resolution tool to determine what the resulting file looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to reset the branch (perhaps this has been published to a shared repository and you don't want people to have to deal with force updates), you can simply revert the upgrade to version 2.0, re-do the upgrade to version 2.0 on a branch off of the version 1.0 import, then merge that branch.

For example (assuming your branch is called `master` and `master` is currently checked out):

```
# create a commit that is the opposite of HEAD, effectively undoing it
git revert HEAD^
# create a new branch based on the original vendor import
git checkout -b vendor <sha1-of-vendor-1.0-commit>
# import the vendor 2.0 code
git read-tree -u --reset master^
git commit -m "vendor 2.0 code"
# merge in the new vendor code
git checkout master
git merge vendor
```

Comment: resetting master isn't an option. i actually ended up using araxis merge's three-way diff/merge capabilities. selected the same file in each of the windows and then different versions in each pane: left team change B, middle common ancestor, right component version 2.0. if i didn't have access to praxis, this would've been the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it this way (assuming `master` is the name of your branch, which it probably isn't):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <SHA of team change B>
git checkout -b vendor-upgrade <SHA of component version 1.0>
# replace contents of working directory with component version 2.0
git add <everything that needs to be added>
git commit -m "component version 2.0"
git checkout master
git merge vendor-upgrade
```

Depending on the nature of the team changes, you may have some merge conflicts to deal with, and it's up to you whether or not to delete the `vendor-upgrade` branch after your done with it or just leave it there for when the inevitable version 3.0 comes out...